# How to simplify Maven life phases in IntelliJ Maven project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have a lot of phases in Maven project at IntelliJ suddenly. It is so weird.

As below

[image]

Is this problem generated by project's pom.xml config?
Is there any way to simplify this and just leaves clean, compile, and package.

Answer (score 0):

These are not **goals**. This are the [life-cycle phases in Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) which you can call as you already mentioned **clean**, **compile** and **package**.

Comment: Yes.this is life-cycle phases not goals.I want to simplify those phases. because I rarely use majority of those phases except clean,compile and package.